# Data Catcher on a Server using port monitoring?

Tags: database, http, parsing, listener, port

I am working on project where we may have 1,000's of pieces of hardware in the field all gathering data and reporting it back to a central server.

To get this data from sensor to database the hardware will be programmed with the server address to send it to.  Data will be sent over http port 80.  A json file will be encoded and pushed out via Ethernet where the server will intercepting, parsing and storing the data from each device based on device location and data structure.

My question is are there  well defined ways to configure what I am calling the catcher? What sort of listening socket solutions should I look at?

I have done similar things in the past where data is sent via ftp to a server where I have a cron job (php script) running to look for new files in the destination folder and parse them into a database.  This worked for 1 device but I want to do 1,000's.

Thoughts?

Comment: Port 80 is reserved for HTTP. Will you be using HTTP for these transfers? If so, you can use an HTTP POST and there are many ways of handling that.

Comment: Yes http post will be used for the transfers.  Could you describe methods for handling 1,000s of these a second?

Comment: You could run Apache and a simple PHP script to accept the incoming JSON data and store it to your database, or write it to a file and run a cron job to execute another PHP script to store the data to your database. If PHP doesn't prove fast enough you could use C++ for either or both of these. Depending on the actual data transfer rate you need PHP might well be enough, and easy to implement

Comment: A side thought, which might not be viable for you: you could reduce your loading dramatically if your sensors can buffer data and send it as one larger POST every few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  "Live data" is necessary where traffic could be coming in from 1,000 - 10,000 devices every second.  Using a PHP scripts is similiar to have I've done it in the past where it scans a directy every 10 seconds for new data.  How do I simply make a php script always run to listen on port 80 for all in bound?